# PHP not entering value of hidden input field into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got a site that has a custom select menu which uses jQuery to pass the selected value into the field.  PHP then gets the value of the hidden input field and, should, insert the value into a database.  However, this isn't happening and I'm not sure why.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

**FORM**

```
<form id="scenario_builder" method="post">
    <fieldset for="center">
        <label>Center:</label>
        <div class="select" name="center_menu" id="center_menu">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="option-menu">
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM $centers";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $center_name = "{$row['center']}";
                        echo "<div class='option'>" .$center_name ."</div>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="button" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**FORM PROCESSING**

```
ob_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $center = $_POST["center"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$scenarios`(`id`) VALUES('" .$center ."')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
ob_clean();
echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
```

**JQUERY SELECT MENU**

```
function select_menu(){
    var select = $(".select");
    var option_menu = $(".option-menu");
    var option = $(".option");
    select.on("click", function(){
        $(this).find(option_menu).toggle();
        select = $(this);
        $(this).find(option_menu).each(function(){
            $(".current").hide();
            if($(this).hasClass("current")){
                $(this).removeClass("current");
            }
            else{
                $(this).show().addClass("current");
            }
        })
    })

    option.on("click", function(){
        select.children("p").remove();
        var value = $(this).text();
        select.prepend("<p><input type='hidden' name='center' id='center' value='" +value +"' />" +value +"</p>");
        console.log(value);
    })

    $(document).on("click", function(ev){
        if($(ev.target).closest(".select").length === 0){
            $(".current").hide().removeClass("current");
        }
    })
}
select_menu();
```

**JQUERY EVENT HANDLER**

```
$("input[id='save']").on("click", function(){
        $.post("..php/processing.php", {}, function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                console.log("Data entered.");
            }
            else{
                console.log("Data not entered.");
            }
        }, "json");
    })
```

Comment: are you getting a value in the console log when you click?

Comment: I am, that's why I'm confused

Comment: is it in `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: is it maybe because you use an additional `s` in the variable name...? `$query = "SELECT * FROM $centers";`

Comment: No because that's what the variable name that has the table name is.  The database actually shows that something was entered, but the data is blank.

Comment: Your `$.post` doesn't have a `data` argument so no data is being sent. If you click more than once you willl be duplicating `name` so only the last one will get included in form

Comment: @rjdown, I'm actually not seeing the var_dump output.  I've got it in the form processing script.  Should I place it somewhere else?

Comment: @charlietfl the hidden input field is added with the jQuery script when a user selects an option.  So by the time the user clicks 'save' the field is there.  What do I need to put in the data argument when a user can dynamically change the value?

Comment: read the `$.post` docs. Then look at `serialize()` for the data but you need to fix duplicate names also

Comment: @charlietfl, ok, I'll look at the docs, I don't have any duplicate names though.  Do I?

Comment: sure you will if user is allowed to click more than once

Comment: The input field is removed if the user changes their selection and re added whenever they make a decision.  So at all times, there's only one input field

Comment: @charlietfl Amazing, thank you very much.  Could you please post your solution as an answer?  I'd like to give you credit for it working.

Comment: On an unrelated topic, this: `$center = $_POST["center"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO $scenarios(id) VALUES('" .$center ."')";` is very insecure. You basically allow the client to input arbitrary SQL queries into your database. This is called SQL injection.

Comment: @SirDarius, I know.  Right now this is basically something that's being demo'd for possible production.  I'm the only one who has access to it.  Once the project gets the go ahead, I'm going to have to alter alot in the scripts and work on security and better error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you need to provide data to send using the data argument for `$.post`

You can use `serialize()` to get all data for a form. You also need to revent the browser default submit process when using ajax or the form will submit normally also

It is generally better to bind everyhting to the `submit` event of the form.

```
$('#scenario_builder').submit(function(event){
    /* prevent default submit*/
     event.preventDefault();
     /* do ajax "this" is the form element*/
     $.post("..php/processing.php", $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                console.log("Data entered.");
            }
            else{
                console.log("Data not entered.");
            }
        }, "json");           
});
```

Comment: So if I had multiple select options on the same page, how would I go about handling that.  Would I be able to do so using just the value variable and place it in the serialize function?  Or would I need to place everything in an array in the data parameter in the $.post function?

Comment: could do `name='center[]'` and then `$_POST['center']` will be an array